# Reverse engineer Core Data 'mom' file

Tags: core-data, reverse-engineering

Is there any way to reverse engineer a Core Data 'mom' file (compiled core data model)?

Comment: What's your motivation behind it? You can get a list of entities, relationships and attributes without reverse engineering it.

Comment: I was given an app without its sources which I am trying to understand. How do I get the information you mentioned?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a way to do this easily.

You can import a compiled datamodel file (.mom) into a model design document (.xcdatamodel) using Xcode > Design > Data Model > Import. This will effectively allow you to 'reverse engineer', if you wish, the compiled mom file and inspect it's model.

**Edit:**

In the Xcode 5 and later, the menu is under **Editor->Import**. But this menu will only appear when you click the .xcdatamodel

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done with [momdec](https://github.com/atomicbird/momdec).

Here is a link to [my fork](https://github.com/malhal/momdec) that adds support for to-many relations:

Build the project and then choose show build folder and copy the command line app from Products to your bin folder.

Here is an example of how to reverse engeinner the Notes app model which is a very interesting one, in particular its use of entity inheritance:

```
cd "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot"

momdec System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NotesShared.framework/NoteData.mom ~/Desktop/
```

[image]

Comment: When I build the project nothing happens. I don't see a command line app or anything labeled "Products". Can you please assist?

Comment: Try show build folder in the menu